# Ошибка Member 'System.Windows.Input.ApplicationCommands.Open' not found

Tags: c#, wpf

При создании пользовательского интерфейса WPF возникает такая ошибка. Код

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Open"/>
</Window.CommandBindings>
```

Как это можно исправить?

Comment: А что значит «возникает ошибка»? Ошибка компиляции? Выбрасывается исключение в конструкторе окна?

Comment: Добавьте ваш обработчик `Executed="..."`

Comment: Возникает ошибка значит внизу окна Visual Studio мне пишет, что есть ошибка. Добавление Executed не помогло.